# Uploading a picture to a Password Protected Directory using libcurl and C++

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to upload pictures using c++ application with libcurl to my server, the file in my server is a protected directory, I tried everything I know but it didn't work.

```
struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
        const char * Picture = "C:\xxxx";

        FILE *fd = fopen(Picture, "rb");
        struct stat file_info;
        fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info);

        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "user : xxxx");
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "password : xxxxx");
        headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, "Content-Type: image/jpeg");


        curl = curl_easy_init();

            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxx.000webhostapp.com/Pictures");
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if (res != CURLE_OK)
    {

        MessageBox::Show("Picture Failed");

    }


        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

        curl_global_cleanup();
```

Comment: So tell us exactly what response you get and what exactly "protected directory" means. What auth does it require?

Comment: Yes but **exactly** how does it want that. There are numerous different ways that can be provided and you have not yet shown us what headers your server responds with.

Comment: That's not how HTTP authentication works. I'm sure that curl library's documentation will have plenty of examples of how to handle HTTP authentication. You'll definitely not be able to do that just by trying to add random headers to your HTTP request. Trial & error is not going to work. Read the docs. (And this assumes that all you're talking about is standard HTTP authentication, and some custom-written hack that only your server knows anything about, with regards to how it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user` and `password` are not HTTP headers, so you should not be passing them via [`CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html).  Use [`CURLOPT_USERNAME`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_USERNAME.html) and [`CURLOPT_PASSWORD`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PASSWORD.html) instead.  Also look at [`CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH.html).

Try this:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

...

const char *Picture = "C:\\xxxx";

FILE *fd = fopen(Picture, "rb");
if (!fd)
{
    MessageBox::Show("Cannot Open Picture File");
}
else
{
    struct stat file_info;
    fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl)
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Cannot Initialize CURL Session");
    }    
    else
    {
        struct curl_slist *headerlist = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: image/jpeg");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://xxxx.000webhostapp.com/Pictures");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "xxxx");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "xxxxx");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);    
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("Picture Failed");
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    fclose(fd);
}

...

curl_global_cleanup();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Remy, now I had access to my file and I get as response (301 Moved Permanently ) (before it's says that password and username are required ) but actualy I can't find the picture that I has sent in the file.

Comment: @A.kame 301 is a redirect. The server is telling you that the requested resource is located at a different URL.  You need to repeat the same request to the URL reported in the response's `Location` header, which you can get with the [`CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.html) option of [`curl_easy_getinfo()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html).  Or, you can enable the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html) option of `curl_easy_setopt()` and let libcurl handle the repeat for you.